# Sass --watch specifying unix_newlines

Tags: command-line, sass

I can't seem to enable Sass to output my css file using unix newlines, which results in conflicts every time a different develop compiles from a .scss file and commits the compiled file (our production environment relies on the compiled file at the moment).

I have Windows 7, Ruby 1.93 and sass 3.2.1. The [options here](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#options) say you can specify `unix_newlines => true` but I can't figure out where that needs to go in my watch command line?

This is the command I'm using at the moment: `sass --watch scss/main.scss:css/main.css scss/orange.scss:css/orange/orange.css --style nested`.

Adding `--unix_newlines true` doesn't work, it says `invalid option: --unix_newlines`

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line, you should use `--unix-newlines`. The `unix_newlines` config specified in the SASS reference is for use from within a Ruby config file - when used as a command-line flag, the underscore becomes a hyphen.

Comment: You sir, are amazing! Thanks. Don't know why I didn't think to do that, haha.